# Polynomials tending to $\exp (t^2/2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, exponential-function, products, infinite-product

I need to show this, I got how it should work but I don't find a proper way to demonstrate it. Any thoughts ?

$$ \lim\limits_{N \to + \infty} \prod\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(1+ n \frac{t^2}{N^2} \right) = \exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right) $$

Thank you if you took time considering it

Comment: Take the log of the product.  Perhaps that helps?

Comment: What you want to prove is not that a polynomial tends to the exponential function but, rather, that a sequence of polynomials converges to the exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Taking the logarithm and developing the logarithm with Taylor, the linear term is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}n\frac{t^2}{N^2}=\frac{(N-1)N}2\frac{t^2}{N^2}$$ which tends to $t^2/2$. The next terms vanish because of larger powers of $N$ at the denominator.

Comment: (+1) didn't see your answer before I posted.

Comment: @robjohn: no worries. For this problem, Taylor is the "King's highway". I wonder if there are alternatives.